# mongo import an empty array get error?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

this is about mongodb.

as we know,mongo offer import and export through array by argument --jsonArray,but there is problem:

I have a empty collection,and I execute
`mongoexport -d test -c myCollection -o --jsonArray mycol.json`

I got a json file:[].

And then I execute
`mongoimport -d test -c myCollection --jsonArray mycol.json`

I got an error:
 Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character ']' looking for beginning of value.

I mean,it's mongo himself export the json,but he cannot recognise it.It's some weird.

Comment: You're importing an empty array, why?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ before import,I do backup by export getting an empty array ,and then some error occurred,so I need to  roll back,that's why I import an empty array

Comment: I consider this as mongoimport bug, as importing empty array can appear in some automatic pipelines

Answer (score 0):

You can consider removing the `--jsonArray` flag while running the first command:

```
mongoexport -d test -c myCollection -o mycol.json
```

If the collection is empty, it will output an empty file which will should work when importing with:

```
mongoimport -d test -c myCollection mycol.json
```